# Query parameter to filter

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to make a query parameter to influence the analizer, so for example if the user search for field_name:value I need that this parameter influence a custom filter.

I think I have to plug the query parser to do this, is this correct?
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "influence the analyzer". If you need to custom field handling e.g. "field_name:value" expanding to "field_A:value AND field_B:value" -- custom search field (via Solr DynamicField) will be much simpler to implement that custom query analyzer.

Comment: I'll explain what I need: I need to make the filter to be instantiated using a parameter that will be passed through the query. For instance I need the synonym filter to load different synonym file for different value of the fq parameter. The fq parameter is under my control, because of my infrastructure, so I set this, I only want to modify the Synonym Factory to load different files for different fq value. But if there is another solution, I'm open to all solutions.